# speeding up dialog show

Tags: android, button, colors

I have a problem with very slow showing up a ColorPicker Dialog after pressing button.
My app should work like this:

1. Show 8 buttons
2. After clicking on a button, show dialog with ColorPicker, and set picked colour to the button
3. After clicking on another button show another dialog, with initial colour of that button

I'm creating ColorPicker for each button, because don't know how to use one ColorPicker with ability to change initial colour. 8 different ColorPickers each saves last picked colour for the button assigned so no problems here. Though I will have to change it in future.

The problem is, that on the beginning, ColorPicker dialog is showing up ~2s after clicking on button(!) After using it once, clicking on the same button shows Picker much faster. What is the reason for this?

This is my code (sorry, beginner)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void pickButtonColor(final Button button) {

        final ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = ColorPickerDialog.createColorPickerDialog(this, R.style.CustomColorPicker);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                colorPickerDialog.setOnColorPickedListener(new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorPickedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onColorPicked(int color, String hexVal) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    }
                });
                colorPickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button4));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button5));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button6));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button7));
    pickButtonColor((Button) findViewById(R.id.button8));

}
```